# How to show digits after points in SQL?

Tags: sql

I use free online SQL editot:

https://www.programiz.com/sql/online-compiler/

I create a column: 9/5. I want to get 1.8 but instead I get 1.
I also tried to use round, but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
select first_name, 
9 /5,
round(9/5, 2)
from Customers
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Integer division. Do `1.0 * 9 / 5` to get decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may force decimal division by using a decimal either in the numerator or denominator:

```sql
SELECT first_name, 9.0 / 5 AS val  -- 1.8
FROM customers;
```

Comment: TY. and what if I want to use a coulmn1/column2 instead of 9.0/5. Both of them integar

Comment: You could use: `1.0 * column1 / column2` ... introduce a float into the calculation